# Echoing to /dev/stdout does not appear in 'docker logs'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

I'm running my rails application inside docker and when I do `docker logs` I would like to see my application log, so I made the following change in `application.rb`. I have set `logger` to stdout. 
`config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`.

The logs are getting displayed in `/dev/stdout` but it doesn't show up when I do `docker logs container_id`.

Comment: Did you try with `docker logs -f <container_id>` in order to follow logs output in real-time?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it returned nothing

Comment: I hope you restarted the container after making the change. Also, check if the logger is being overridden in `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: I'm not restarting the container, and logger is being overridden in development.rb